# Outlook Save attachment to file not working

Tags: vba, outlook, windows-7, outlook-2010

I've used this VBA code several times before, on the same machine. Now I've set up a new profile on this machine and I'm using the exact same code I have used before, but now it doesn't work.

Code below:

```
Public Sub SaveAttachmentsToDisk(MItem As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim oAttachment As Outlook.Attachment
Dim sSaveFolder As String
sSaveFolder = "C:\Whatever folder I need it in"
For Each oAttachment In MItem.Attachments
oAttachment.SaveAsFile sSaveFolder & oAttachment.DisplayName
Next
End Sub
```

Then I create a rule to run a script, set it up like I set up previously on other account and it turns into (Client Only rule) and when I try to run it it says "Client only rule can only run when Outlook is running", but outlook is running though...

I also get this error:

[image]

Anyone has any idea of what's wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to run the code under the debugger and find the exact property or method call which fails or gives an error?

Answer (score 0):

Typically the `C:\` drive requires admin privileges for writing/creating files. Try to choose another drive or folder for saving attached files.

Comment: Hi, I tried other folder, Z:\ folder and doesn't work. But I've used it with c:\ before with no problems. Whatever the problem is seems to be related with the Client Rule problem I would have thought...

Comment: Have you tried to run the code under the debugger and find the exact property or method call which fails or gives an error?

Comment: I have a problem... I'm not admin on my pc and I have no other drives. Is there a workaround? I'm getting no error messages

Comment: The application data folder doesn't require admin privileges.

Answer (score 0):

Ignore my question! Rookie mistake! I'm so sorry for wasting your time fellas.

I'm missing a slash on my path file.....

Thanks for your help anyway people!

Comment: So, my advice helped.